# system being absolute continous

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

The classical Rudin--Shapiro sequence $r_n\in\{-1,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ satisfy the following inequality.

$(\int_{0}^{1}\left|\sum_{n<N}r_ne^{2\pi in(\theta)}\right|^{2}d\theta)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq \sup_{\theta\in[0,1]}\left|\sum_{n<N}r_ne^{2\pi in\theta}\right|\leq C\sqrt{N}$. The left hand side of the inequality equals $\sqrt{N}$.

My question is for a system to be absolutely continuous relative to Lebesgue measure. The Fourier transform of the measure say $\widehat{\mu}(k)$ tends to zero as the limit of $k$ tends to zero. Does the above inequality suggests absolute continuity?

Comment: What does it mean for a "system" to be absolutely continuous? What measure $\mu$ are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, perhaps its better to ask from the above inequality, whether I can show the Fourier transform decays to zero

Comment: The Fourier transform of _what_?